# Spring Boot @Qualifier alone is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource

I am trying to create multiple datasources. This is what I have in my configuration class: if I comment @Primary annotation, it's throwing an exception and the application is not starting, why is @Qualifier alone not working? Why is it insisting to make one of the datasource primary?

```
@Bean
//@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource fDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.secondDatasource")
public DataSource sDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateOne(@Qualifier("fDataSource") DataSource ds) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateTwo(@Qualifier("sDataSource") DataSource ds ) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
}
```

I am seeing the below in the console:

> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer
>   to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean
>   that should be consumed

Comment: your code looks fine, btw are your sure Qualifier import is correct?

Comment: you have declared two jdbctemplate bean. Add @Qualifier for both of them. And then do you have any autoconfigurer beans (may be from spring) trying to use datasource bean, Attach full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

It is because autoconfiguration. Spring(especially spring-boot) aims to make configuration easy in very common cases. In the most of cases you just need one datasource or one of your datasource is main(primary). The autoconfiguration of datasources rely on this assume.

If you have special configuration(or not very common) requirements you need to make these configuration manually and may not use "spring-boot". But this way is complicated. You can go further in spring documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try disable spring auto initialization.

```
spring.datasource.initialize=false
```

In addition, i am not sure how are you using your   jdbctemplate bean. As you have declared two of them, either add @Primary or add @Qualifier for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

you can put `Qualifier` annotation on each of the datasource with respective name, I guess this should fix it.

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
@Qualifier("fDataSource")
public DataSource fDataSource() {
  return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.secondDatasource")
@Qualifier("sDataSource")
public DataSource sDataSource() {
  return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateOne(@Qualifier("fDataSource") DataSource ds) {
  return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateTwo(@Qualifier("sDataSource") DataSource ds ) {
  return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
}
```

Comment: Even if we have not used @Qualifier("fDataSource"), by default a datasource object with name fDataSource should be available right?

Comment: yes, default is Autowire.BY_NAME, unless there is a name conflict